# Request with CoreData

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Here is my problem :

My CoreData model have two entity : Players and Results. The important properties of Players are :
- ratingTypePlayer, which is a String.
- resultsPlayer which is a Too-Many Relationship with Results as Destination. The Inverse relationship is playerResult.

I wish to obtain an array with all the Results of the Players which ratingTypePlayer is equal to "Toto". I don't find this kind of example.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You mean, like a fetch request?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ratingTypePlayer == %@", @"Toto"]];
NSArray *players = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

If you wanted an array of the "resultsPlayer" relationships, you could do:

```
NSArray *results = [players valueForKey:@"resultsPlayer"];
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact "NSArray *results = [players valueForKey:@"resultsPlayer"];" return an Array of Array (an array for each player with his results) so I had to code a for loop in a for loop to have the complete list of results.